# Sum all properties in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following object:

```
{"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional":"299"}
```

I want to sum all this values and print It out. How can I sum the properties values? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Iterate over the object properties using `for(var in)`
2. Use `parseInt` since some of the *integers* are in string form

```js
var obj = {"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional":"299"};
var sum = 0;

for(var key in obj){
  sum += parseInt(obj[key]);
  }

document.write(sum);
```

Comment: Better id you don't use document.write, use a function and you add hasOwnProperty

Comment: @RaúlMartín `document.write` is an easy way to display a result in a code snippet. Using a function is the question asker's job. And finally, why `hasOwnProperty` given the code above? What would it do?

Comment: wherever you use key in obj you would use hasOwnProperty, you don't know the origin of the object. You need trust in your code for reuse it in the future.

Comment: @RaúlMartín, but in this case we do know the origin of the object. It is that of the one in the OP code. Furthermore, I explicitly declared it with `var obj =` in my anser

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way of doing it using ES5's [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var obj = {"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional":"299"};
var sum = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(prev, current, index) {
    return prev + (+obj[current]);
}, 0);
console.log(sum); // 746
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc08ynz7/)

Comment: This is a nice alternative to the other 6 similar answers! ^1

Comment: @AmmarCSE Thanks. I thought it was an interesting problem to solve, I guess so did everyone else!

Comment: Why not?

     Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (previous, key) {          
         return previous + (parseInt(obj[key] || 0));
     }, 0)

Comment: @RaúlMartín True, would save the ternary. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

My for-less version:

```js
var obj = {"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional":"299"};

function sumProperties(obj) {
   return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
   .map(function(item){ return +obj[item];})
   .reduce(function(acc,item) { return acc + item; });
}

document.write(sumProperties(obj));
```

Comment: Didnt see this one. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
var obj = {"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional": 299}
```

you can do it very easily with the [lodash](https://lodash.com) library:

```
var result = _.sum(obj);
```

If some of your values aren't numbers, you need to map them to numbers first:

```
var result = _.sum(_.map(obj, function(n){
     return +n;
     //or parseInt(n) or parseInt(n,10)
}));
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UQs1aTCJ8qe1kG15G4x7?p=preview

Comment: i tried the same with lodash 4.17.10, its giving zero. ? Is it a version issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var sum_object = {"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional":"299"};
var sum = 0;

for( var index in sum_object ){
    sum += parseInt(sum_object[index]);
    console.log("Val: ",sum_object[index], sum);
};

console.log(sum);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abvuh5m0/

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional":"299"};


function sum(obj){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var key in obj){
      if (obj. hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          sum += parseInt(obj[key]) || 0;  
       }
    }
    return sum
}

console.log(sum(obj));
```

`parseInt(obj[key]) || 0;`  is important id the value is not a number

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash:

```
var obj = {"speed":299,"equipment":49,"teleabb":49,"additional":50,"optional":"299"};

var val = _.sumBy(_.values(obj), function(v) {
   return parseInt(v)
});
```

Example: https://codepen.io/dieterich/pen/dyymoxM?editors=0012

Answer (score -1):

```
var sum = 0;
for(var key in objects) {
    sum += parseInt(objects[key]);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: duplicate answer